# import .mbtiles[raster+png/jpg] from device can't view in Maptiler App

Tags: raster, mapbox, android, mbtiles, maptiler

I am working with maptiler application in android[Kotlin+MVVM]. everything working fine except loading local .mbtiles map file. when I download a .mbtiles file from internet and load in to my android phone and then try to import it to my maptiler application, it will load in to database successfully but can not seen on screen . means there is some conflict to view that **.mbtiles [raster+png/jpg]** file. it gives following error:

```
Unable to parse resourceUrl maptiler://{filepath}
```

when remove maptiler:// from scheme and use direct file Uri it gives another error like:

```
Failed to load source maptiler-overlay-0: invalid value .at offset 0
```

now i did some try like change style.json with **[style-local.json, style-cdn.json, style-mb.json]** but cant get any success.
can Anyone had face this type of error or any idea how to resolve it ??
OR
can Anyone tell me the proper way to load local .mbtiles[raster+png/jpg]file in to maptiler[mapbox] app .??

Answer (score 0):

just update

**MapboxGLAndroidSDK-release.aar**

library from 8.* to 9.2.1 and also update its corresponding supported libraries.

you can download from this [link](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-native/releases)